# Animating an image using "animation templates" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, animation

I don't know whats this method called in general, but can i use a single template image that consists of multiple frames like this:

[image]

And then render it as a single animated image using javascript?

Or should i just make gifs and not bother, as this would be too hard to do?

Appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: you mean to use sprite sheets?? & what have you tried to do so?

Comment: I guess that's what they are called, i haven't tried anything yet as i don't even know where to start.

Comment: You can assign it to an element as background-image and offset it as needed. this is called "css sprites".

Comment: Ah i see, googling "css sprites" yields many good tutorials on how to do this, thanks!

Comment: GSAP is a good library to do this kind of stuff

Comment: that looks really good! thank you for the suggestion! @SethWhite